# Update action for nested resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a nested resource in my routes.rb

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do
  resource :preferences, :only => [:create,:show,:update,:destroy]
end
```

Now to update the preference of a user, I'm using

```
preferences = Preference.where(:user_id => user_id).update_all(preferences_request)
render json: preferences, status: 200
```

But I feel it's not a good practice to use `update_all` as each user has only one preference. And also I can't use `render :json => preferences` as `preferences` will have the value `1` instead of an actual hash object with all the table attributes.
What is the best way to update the preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply load the preference and then perform an [`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update).

```
preference = Preference.find_by!(user_id: user_id)
preference.update(preferences_request)

render json: preference
```

<strike>You have to deal with the case the query returns nil (because the user doesn't exist, for example).</strike> `preferences_request` must be a Hash of `attributes => values`. Of course, you may want to validate it as well and/or use the strong parameters feature to filter our attributes you don't want to be updated.

Comment: `Preference.where(user_id: user_id).take` can be replaced with `Preference.find_by!(user_id: user_id)` for brevity. :-)

Comment: It makes sense, I updated the answer @Drenmi. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have User 1-1 Preference with the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :preference
end

class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

According to [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) method **update_all** has been designed for update related objects in batch straight through database layer bypass ActiveRecord:

> Updates all records in the current relation with details given. This
>   method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight
>   to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it
>   does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. Values passed
>   to `update_all` will not go through ActiveRecord's type-casting
>   behavior. It should receive only values that can be passed as-is to
>   the SQL database.

But probably you need to pass objects through validation and return objects back where **update** method may suit your needs better, see [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update):

> Updates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database,
>   if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the
>   object was saved successfully to the database or not.

Back to your question, you have 1-1 mapping, so there is no need to update multiple records. Correct me if I'm wrong:

```
class PreferencesController
  def update
    preference = User.find(params[:id]).preference
    preference.update(params[:preference])
    return json: preference.as_json
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually with this kind of request you'd make two queries. One to find the `User` and another to update it.

Your request should be to the URL `users/1/preferences` (replace 1 with the user id that you are trying to update)

Then the controller code can look like

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  user.preferences.update!(preference_request)
  render json: user.preferences
end
```

The benefit of doing it this way is it will appropriately throw a 404 error if the User does not exist, and it will throw a 500 with validation errors if the update fails for some reason.

Read about HTTP status codes and how they can help you [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)